# Sum daily values into monthly values

Tags: r

I am trying to sum daily rainfall values into monthly totals for a record over 100 years in length. My data takes the form:

```
Year     Month     Day     Rain
1890       1        1         0
1890       1        2       3.1
1890       1        3       2.5
1890       1        4      15.2
```

In the example above I want R to sum all the days of rainfall in January 1890, then February 1890, March 1890.... through to December 2010. I guess what I'm trying to do is create a loop to sum values. My output file should look like:

```
Year    Month    Rain
1890      1       80.5
1890      2       72.4
1890      3       66.8
1890      4       77.2
```

Any easy way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Look at `?aggregate`. Something like `aggregate(Rain~Year+Month, dd, sum)` if your data is in a data.frame named `dd`. No loop needed.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @MrFlick. Unfortunately this gives the following error message: 

Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1373L, 1077L, 750L, 1605L, 543L, 91L, 1114L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: That means your data has likely been read into R incorrectly. From your sample is appears that Rain is a numeric column but your error implies its a factor column. Check for non-numeric values in there.

Comment: Indeed you're right @MrFlick. I used read.delim rather than read.table so was not getting numeric values. Sorted now. One final question with this approach:

My output is now organised as Jan 1890, Jan 1891, Jan 1892 etc. rather than Jan 1890, Feb 1890, Mar 1890 etc. Is there an easy way to reorganise the sequence?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr` for some pleasing syntax

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(Rain = sum(Rain))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @cdeterman. Unfortunately I cannot seem to install the dplyr package. I get a message to say the package is successfully unpacked and MD5 syms checked, but then the library is unfound when I load it.

Comment: @DJ-AFC, what else does it say?  It is difficult to troubleshoot with only that information.  Try restarting R and installing the package again.

Comment: This is another easy approach aside from the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it can be beneficial to convert it to a time-series class like `xts`, then you can use functions like `apply.monthly()`.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(1890,5), 
  Month = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
  Day = 1:5,
  rain = rexp(5)
)

> head(df)
      Year Month Day      rain
    1 1890     1   1 0.1528641
    2 1890     1   2 0.1603080
    3 1890     1   3 0.5363315
    4 1890     2   4 0.6368029
    5 1890     2   5 0.5632891
```

Convert it to `xts` and use `apply.monthly()`:

```
library(xts)
dates <- with(df, as.Date(paste(Year, Month, Day), format("%Y %m %d")))
myXts <- xts(df$rain, dates)

> head(apply.monthly(myXts, sum))
                [,1]
1890-01-03 0.8495036
1890-02-05 1.2000919
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @J.R. This is an interesting solution but it does not work in cases where there are missing dates in my original data - so cbinding these dates to my original data is then not possible.

Comment: This was just an example. Missing dates are no problem, just use your own dates instead and not my date-sequence.

Comment: @DJ-AFC I updated the example to make it more applicable to your case.